# MySQL Syntax error - at line 1

Tags: php, mysql, syntax, insert

I am stuck at an error in my PHP. Someone that can help me?

I get this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'fulltext, surl, burl, date) VALUES 'Webite is online!', 'This is a short text lo' at line 1

And this is my code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if(!empty($_POST['titel']) && !empty($_POST['stext']) && !empty($_POST['fulltext']) && !empty($_POST['surl']) && !empty($_POST['burl'])) {
            $titel = secure($_POST['titel']);
            $stext = secure($_POST['stext']);
            $fulltext = secure($_POST['fulltext']);
            $surl = secure($_POST['surl']);
            $burl = secure($_POST['burl']);
            $date = date('d/m/y H:i:s');

                    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO news (titel, stext, fulltext, surl, burl, date) VALUES '".$titel."', '".$stext."', '".$fulltext."', '".$surl."', '".$burl."', '".$date."'")or die(mysql_error());
                    if($sql) {
                        echo('News posted succesful.');
                        echo('<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3" />');
                    } else {
                        echo'There was an error, please try again.';
                        echo('<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3" />');
                    }
        } else {
            echo('Not all fields are filled.');
            echo('<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3" />');
        }
    } else {
        echo('
        <form method="post" action="#">
        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2">
        <tr>
        <td>Titel</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="titel" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Short news</td>
        <td><textarea name="stext" rows="4" cols="50" ></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Long news</td>
        <td><textarea name="fulltext" rows="4" cols="50" ></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>150x150 image url</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="surl" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <tr>
        <td>*x* image url</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="burl" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post" /></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </form>');
    }
?>
```

Comment: Missing starting and ()

Comment: "INSERT INTO news (titel, stext, fulltext, surl, burl, date) VALUES ('".$titel."', '".$stext."', '".$fulltext."', '".$surl."', '".$burl."', '".$date."'")

Comment: `Insert into table (column) values (values)`.... Also use backtick for date column

Comment: @devpro added the backticks by date and added () at values, still the same error... and how do you mean you miss the starting?

Comment: Backtick for date is not an issue here add bracket between values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all stop using `mysql_*` its deprecated and close in PHP 7. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Issue in your query is that you are missing the brackets of `VALUES ()`:

**EXAMPLE**:

```
INSERT INTO table (column1...) VALUES (values1...)
```

**Your Modified Query:**

```
INSERT INTO news (titel, stext, `fulltext`, surl, burl, date) VALUES ('".$titel."', '".$stext."', '".$fulltext."', '".$surl."', '".$burl."', '".$date."'")
```

**Side note:**

Make sure column `titel` is correct name.

**UPDATE:**

And as Mr Barmar @barmar mentioned `fulltext` is MYSQL reserve word so you need to add backtick around this column.

Comment: Thanks for your help Devpro!, your best help was saying that i needed to quit MySQL and start using Mysqli or DPO, and i did; changed the code to msqli and all of sudden it works now thanks!

Comment: @pindaworld don't care which answer u chose but happy to know u r using mysqli good work bro

Answer (score 1):

`fulltext` is a MySQL [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html). If you want to use it as a column name, you need to put it in backticks.

You're also missing parentheses around the list of values.

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO news (titel, stext, `fulltext`, surl, burl, date) VALUES ('".$titel."', '".$stext."', '".$fulltext."', '".$surl."', '".$burl."', '".$date."')")or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: It should be obvious from the error message, since it says the error starts at `fulltext`.

Comment: I did noticed it thanks, already changed that after i posted this but thanks for noticing!